# use ajax to submit/pull values from time picker

Tags: jquery, ajax

How do I save data into database via ajax, and pull same saved date back to be immediately viewed in the dom by the user.

This is the code I have for the forms to be saved :

```
<p>
<b>Time In : </b>
    <select>
        <?php
            $time = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1);
            for ($i = 28800; $i < 42600; $i += 1800) {  // 1800 = half hour, 86400 = one day
            printf('<option value="%1$s">%1$sam</option>',
            date('g:i', $time + $i), date('g:i a', $time + $i + 1800));
            }
            for ($i = 43200; $i < 66400; $i += 1800) {  // 12pm-6pm
            printf('<option value="%1$s">%1$spm</option>',
            date('g:i', $time + $i), date('g:i a', $time + $i + 1800));
            }
        ?>
    </select>
<b>Time Out : </b>
    <select>
        <?php
            $time = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1);
            for ($i = 28800; $i < 42600; $i += 1800) {  // 1800 = half hour, 86400 = one day
            printf('<option value="%1$s">%1$sam</option>',
            date('g:i', $time + $i), date('g:i a', $time + $i + 1800));
            }
            for ($i = 43200; $i < 66400; $i += 1800) {  // 12pm-6pm
            printf('<option value="%1$s">%1$spm</option>',
            date('g:i', $time + $i), date('g:i a', $time + $i + 1800));
            }
            ?>
    </select>
<button type="button" style="vertical-align: middle;" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" data-target="#addTime">Add Time</button>
</p>
```

The Add Time button should link to the two select forms, and calculate as $start_time to $end_time to be saved in the db.

Comment: The "time out" input is the current date after the insert process? I don't understand so much what you want to do.

Comment: @RodrigoQuiñonesPichioli Think of it like a timeclock system, 08:00(am) would be the Time In, Time Out may be 05:00(pm)

Comment: If you want to do register into database with AJAX (like the title) you can send a post request sending the times separately, execute the query in the backend, get the live times results you want to, and serialize into a JSON structure. So, in the success callback (in the same AJAX request you send), you can build a data injection into the list (DOM).. With data in hand you are free to handle it.